# Katalon Studio not able to run test in Chrome

Tags: katalon-studio

I recorded a test case on Chrome and wanted to run the test. When I run it, it just opens up a browser and doesn't add the URL

If I open in Firefox, the URL is added but the proxy settings default to no proxy (but I am behind a firewall)

How do I get the test to run on either Firefox or Chrome?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

To set proxy in case of `Firefox`, you have to use profiles in `WebDriver`.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.addAdditionalPreference("network.proxy.http", "localhost");
profile.addAdditionalPreference("network.proxy.http_port", "8888");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

To execute testcase in `Chrome`, you need [Chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/).

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
```

You can set proxy like this.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:8888");
options.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options)
```

Comment: @Exzile : You need to set a custom keyword: https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/create_custom_keyword.html